# API call issue with ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I'm Trying to call an API with ionic2, The data provider looks like this.the service returns an array of object.when i serve the app, the data is not displaying in the HTML template. How i can fix that issue.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


  @Injectable()
  export class VideoService {
  videos: any;


  constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Hello videoService Provider');
  }

  getVideos(){
  this.http.get('http://mizikjams-lorisson.rhcloud.com/api/videos.json')
  .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.videos= data.videos; 
  console.log(this.videos);
  });

  }


  }
```

here's the html template code

```
<ion-content class=" mainpage card-background-page "> 
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let video of videos">
  <ion-avatar item-left>
  <img src="{{video.image}}">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{video.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <div class="floatingbtn">
  <ion-fab bottom right edge >
  <button ion-fab color="orange" (click)="search();"><ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab> 
  </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Looks like you read the "videos" and keep them in the service. Do you have any component that uses this service? and this html code, is it attached to any component/page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/JtLm3K?p=preview

make sure you add the provider to the app.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomePage ],
  entryComponents: [ HomePage ],
  bootstrap: [ IonicApp ],
  providers: [VideoService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

provider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


  @Injectable()
  export class VideoService {
  videos: any;


  constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Hello videoService Provider');
  }

  getVideos(){
    return this.http.get('http://mizikjams-lorisson.rhcloud.com/api/videos.json')
    .map(res => res.json());

  }


  }
```

page1.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VideoService } from './videoService'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  appName = 'Ionic App';
  videos:any

  constructor(public navController: NavController, public vs : VideoService) { 

    this.videos = this.vs.getVideos()
  }

}
```

html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let video of (videos | async)?.videos ">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{video.image}}">
        </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{video.title}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank for the prompt reply , i revised the code , still not displaying the datat in the html template .but when i console.log it i see all the objects in the console.but it's not appearing in the html template.

Comment: finally it's working , i had to change a couple things.